# python class act like a list

Tags: python, class, list

Why the following code returns empty after I have added several items in it?

```
class Con(list):

    def __init__(self): pass

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(self)

    def add(self, value)
        self.append(value)

i for i in range(10):
    Con().add(i)

>>> print Con()
# empty space instead of:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

What else I have to define for my class to act like a list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're always creating a new instance of con in each iteration of your loop. You have to create the instance before the loop and add to that instance. Furthermore, you're creating another new instance in the print statement, so that'll turn up empty as well.

Comment: ...and you are missing a `:` on line `def add(self, value)`

Answer (score 5):

You're creating 11 instances of `Con` by calling `Con()` each time through the loop and again when you print.

You want something like:

```
c = Con()
for i in range(10):
    c.add(i)

print c
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you do not save any instance of con. On each `Con()` a new instance gets created. You have to save it somewhere like that:

```
c = Con()
for i in range(10):
    c.add(i)

>>> print c
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```